# LIKE 'X%' OR LIKE 'Y%' OR LIKE 'Z%' =/= LIKE '[XYZ]%'?

Tags: sql, sqlplus

I have an assignment task which is to list the names of employees whose names start with K, M, or S.

The employee table:

```
ENAME
----------
KING
BLAKE
CLARK
JONES
MARTIN
ALLEN
TURNER
JAMES
WARD
FORD
SMITH

ENAME
----------
SCOTT
ADAMS
MILLER
```

Here comes the issue.

When I use the following command, it works, but it's fairly wordy:

```
SQL> SELECT ename from emp where ename LIKE 'K%' OR ename LIKE 'M%' OR ename LIKE 'S%';

ENAME
----------
KING
MARTIN
SMITH
SCOTT
MILLER
```

But when I try this command, which should work, it gives me this:

```
SQL> SELECT ename from emp where ename LIKE '[KMS]%';

no rows selected
```

My understanding is that the [] allows for a wildcard range or specific values, but I don't get why this does not allow to check employees whose names start with K, M, or S.

Comment: "but I don't get why this does not allow to check employees whose names start with K, M, or S" - because (by definition) it selects employees with names that start explictly with 'KMS'

Comment: @MitchWheat According to this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396, it says that the [ ] wildcard allows any single character within the specified range ([a-f]) or set ([abcdef]).

Comment: sqlplus is not TSQL

Comment: Are you using Oracle? I think it doesn't support this feature...

Comment: @ameizing You're not using Microsoft's product, so what Microsoft's documentation says doesn't really matter. [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions016.htm) doesn't mention `[`.

Comment: Ah, I see now, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use left

SELECT ename from emp
WHERE left(ename, 1) in ('M','K','S')

Comment: the problem with doing it this way is it probably won't use an index if one was avaliable

Comment: How big is the table?

Comment: shouldn't you be asking that of the poster? Also, the original 'LIKE' will almost certainly produce a better query plan

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a regular expression (but I see nothing wrong with your original working `LIKE` clause ):

```
SELECT ename from emp
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (ename , '^[KMS]');
```

Ref:. [Pattern-matching Conditions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions007.htm)

Comment: Oracle may be different, but normally, this means "starts with K, or contains M or S", and "starts with K, M or S" can be written as `^(K|M|S)` or simply `^[KMS]`. Note: this isn't `LIKE`, so the fact that `[]` doesn't work with `LIKE` doesn't mean it won't work here.

Comment: Thanks. I though it looked odd. Updated as per your comment.